# Clearing floats with CSS3 without chaging HTML

Tags: html, css

Have found several answers to this question, but they either require me to change my html or just don't work in my case.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="name">Daiel</div>
<div class="amount">30€</div>
<!-- clear here -->
<div class="graph">
 <div class="green" style="width: 42%"></div>
</div>
```

And the following css:

```
div.name{float:left;}
div.amount{float:right; }
div.amount:after { content: " "; display: table; clear: both; }
div.graph { height: 26px; width: 100%; background: #d9d9d9;}
div.graph .green { height: 25px; background: #a2af00;}
```

And i can't get the bars to be below the texts. 
Basically i want .amount to auto clear my floats, so i'm guessing i need a :after.

Please see [jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/13/)

What am i doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand..... do you want 2 rows?
1) first one with "Daiel" on the left and "30€" on the right
2) second one with gray background and inside it a green bar

???

Comment: Adding `clear:both;` to the graph div should fix it. http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/14/

Comment: Here you are http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/15/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/17/ and http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/16/

Comment: If you want *any* content right after `.amount` to clear, use this rule `div.amount + * { clear:both; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/5hyHg/

Comment: thanks, adding clear:both directly works, but really i want all content after .amount to clear itself, so thanks keaykraine will use div.amount + * { clear:both; }, but how come i can't get it working with div.amount:after ?

Answer (score 1):

do you really want to use floats?

why not use this instead. same HTML mark up, just the css,

```
div.graph { height: 26px; width: 100%; background: #d9d9d9;}
div.graph .green { height: 25px; background: #a2af00;}

.name, .amount{ display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 49%; }
.name{ text-align; left; }
.amount{ text-align: right; }
```

Comment: Oh how I love those widths of 49%. Good old days... They are forever gone now with `box-sizing`...

Comment: they will not be in the same line if i use 50% :) because of inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Add class "clearfix" on graph div..

**[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/18/)**

**CSS:**

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   line-height: 0;
   height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

Good luck...